# Live overclocking on Windows

Tags: windows-xp, dell-inspiron, overclocking

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589826/live-overclocking-overvolting-in-linux) question and just had to ask.

How can I do this on my own PC, where do I find this software if it exists for your computer and what can I do?

I never considered overclocking before because I know myself and I know I'd mess up my hardware in some stupid accident or mistake, but if I can just do it through software it'd be nice to give it a shot.

It's an Inspiron 1520 laptop, and I'd be happy to provide any other information you need to assist me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dell's in general cannot be overclocked using software, they have a proprietary bios. A few of their expensive desktops could be overclocked and the software was provided by Dell, it is some of the XPS series.

There are some articles on the net about "pin modding" of the cpu itself, but is not for the faint of heart. Each pin mod is specific to each cpu and stepping code. Google `pin mod intel` or `pin mod (and your processor series)`

Some motherboards can be overclocked by changing some values of the PLL chip that is on the motherboard, only works for certain pll's
http://www.overclockers.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-223775.html

**Any of this overclocking can damage hardware permanently and is complicated on a Dell.**

Don't forget to let the smoke out of the case when you are done! ; ->

.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it depends on your board manufacturer. e.g., I have a Gigabyte motherboard with a windows app for clock speeds and voltage that's made BY/FOR Gigabyte boards (EasyTune6). It's brand/model specific. In a similar way my video card is an EVGA and I use the EVGA utility (EVGA Precision) for controlling clock speeds and voltage.

Comment: How can I find out my board manufacturer?

Comment: Try this: http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html Fwiw, however, I don't think you're going to have much luck overclocking a laptop. In all likelihood your CPU isn't going to have much wiggle room. In addition, heat is a huge factor with overclocking, and there's not much you can do to keep a laptop much cooler.

Comment: Okay, where in that would I look? I've installed the program.

Comment: Mainboard tab. Not to sound like a jerk, but if you can't figure that out you probably shouldn't be overclocking your gear.

Comment: Fair enough. I actually didn't notice the Motherboard section on there, just breezed on past.

Comment: This is what I've got: http://i.imgur.com/C5hKM.png

Comment: You have a generic Dell/Intel motherboard. I point you to read @Moab's answer. And as a former owner of a 1520 - you **cannot** overclock the processor.  Also: The 1520 is an oven stove.